# Web came resize image asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, capture

I am using the below link to upload image via web cam. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/528929/Capture-images-using-web-camera-in-ASP-NET. It's working fine, but I am unable to increase the image size. The default size is width="450"`height="200"` but I want to increase it up to `width="650"` height="400"`.    Object> Please help. Thanks

Comment: Please post your code directly in your question. Also please read and edit your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve BTW making a mistake in the *title* is just lazy and disrespectful, you could have at least read what you posted.

Comment: <object width="450" height="200">
                                          <param name="movie" value="WebcamResources/save_picture.swf">
                                          <embed src="WebcamResources/save_picture.swf" width="450" height="200"></embed>
                                         </object>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ImageResizer. It's relatively simple to adjust image sizes with its API. Make sure images have enough resolution  to begin with.

[ImageResizer Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/)